# UISlider added to a UITableViewCell weird behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I have a slider added to cell in the storyboard. In `cellForRowAtIndexPAth:`I get the slider and add a label to the slider's thumb programmatically, and then return the cell. the code is as below

```
UISlider *forceDelaySlider = (UISlider *)[cell1 viewWithTag:102];
forceDelaySlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
forceDelaySlider.maximumValue = 10.0;
forceDelaySlider.value = [Settings sharedInstance].forceDelay;

[forceDelaySlider addTarget:self     action:@selector(forceDelaySliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 UIImageView *handleView = [forceDelaySlider.subviews lastObject];

 if (forceDelaySliderLabel)
 {
    [forceDelaySliderLabel removeFromSuperview];
    forceDelaySliderLabel = nil;
 }

 forceDelaySliderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:handleView.bounds];
 forceDelaySliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", forceDelaySlider.value];
 forceDelaySliderLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 forceDelaySliderLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                [forceDelaySliderLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

 [handleView addSubview:forceDelaySliderLabel];

 return cell1,
```

Now When the table is presented the label on the slider wont appear after the table loads.It appears plain as below

[image: Plain slider]

After scrolling the tableview up and down the slider with label appears as below
[image: Slider with label]

Why is this happening? I am stuck. Please help me out with this weird behaviour.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it would be better to add the slider with its label in the init method of a custom cell. You should only need to add the target action, and set the value of the slider and label in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This leads to cleaner code on your controller, and eliminates the need to check if there already is a slider in your cell.

Comment: @rdelmar I have a feeling that your suggestion would work

Comment: @rdelmar I will try it out and let you know again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `[cell1 viewWithTag:102]` or `[forceDelaySlider.subviews lastObject]` return a `nil` view when the cell is first loaded?  Most likely one of the two doesn't exist until after a layout or render pass.

---

Rather than assume that `[forceDelaySlider.subviews lastObject]` is always going to be a `UIImageView` of the thumb you should subclass `UISlider` and add your own `UILabel` subview.  Then you can change its position according to the value you return from [`thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:).  This implementation will survive any refactoring of the `UISlider` class by Apple in future iOS versions.

Comment: I tried subclassing of UISlider and adding the UIlabel in the init method by overiding it and using the same code to add the label in the subview. It still gives the same effect, no change. But you other suggestion of using thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value: works perfectly fine. I just wanted to do it by adding it as subview of the thumb as there wont be any need to write the code for adjusting the frame of the label(Some how wont work).